# Definition of expected values for random variables which are continuous functions

Tags: probability

What is the actual definition for expected values for random variables which are continuous functions ?

Actually I was solving a question which read as "there are $n$ boats where boat $i$ can arrive any time within $a_{i}$ minutes, what is the expected number minutes one has to wait before he finds a boat", Then in this case $E[X] = \sum xP[x]$ , and $P(x)$ would be the probability that you had to wait for x minutes, which means $P(x) = (1-x/a_{1})(1-x/a_{2}) .. (1-x/a_{n})$.
But this summation will be over all real numbers from $0$ to $min(a_{1},a_{2}..,a_{n})$ . So what would be $E[X]$ now ? 
I was confused between

1)$E[X] = \int x P(x) dx$

2)$E[X] = \int x dP(x) $

Another method I thought was using random ***indicator*** variables $R_i$ for events $E_i$ ,where I define $E_i$ as the event that one had to wait till $i$th minute. Then again

$E[X] = \sum E[R_{i}] = \sum P(E_i) $, again we have to extend this sum for real numbers, so should the answer be simply $\int P(x) dx$ ?

So overall my doubt is how to extend this discrete values summations for real numbers ?

Comment: specify exactly what you mean by $P(x)$. I suspect something like $P\left\{ X=x\right\}$ in the discrete case. Is it the so-called
density in the continuous case?

Comment: Yes, for a continuous random variable $X$ the expectation is $E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x)dx$ where $f(x)$ is the density of $X$. Have a look here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Univariate_continuous_random_variable

Comment: @drhab: Like for the example I gave, I know that probability of having frequency $x$ is a function $P(x) = (1-x/2)(1-x/3)$ for $0<=x<=2$ , I don't know if this should be called a density function ?

Comment: I should think so, but am suspicious. It must satisfy $\int_{0}^{2}P\left(x\right)dx=1$.
Does it?

Comment: @drhab: No, it is not equal to 1. Also when is $\int X dP(x)$ used ?

Comment: Another possibility would be that it is the function $P\left\{ X\leq x\right\} $ but then it should get 'bigger' (I don't
know the right English word for this) when $x$ gets bigger, wich
is not the case. What remains is the possibility $P\left(x\right)=P\left\{ X\geq x\right\} $.
That fits with $P\left(0\right)=1$ and $P\left(2\right)=0$. Then
you get $-\int_{0}^{2}xdP\left(x\right)$ as expectation. Don't overlook the minus here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distribution function is by definition

> $F\left(x\right)=P\left\{ X\leq x\right\} $ and we have $E\left[X\right]=\int xdF\left(x\right)$.

The $P\left(x\right)=\left(1-x/a_{1}\right)\cdots\left(1-x/a_{n}\right)$
(and $=0$ if $x<0$ or $x>\min\left\{ a_{1},\cdots,a_{n}\right\} $)
you mention is the function $P\left\{ X>x\right\} $.

So here we have
$F\left(x\right)=1-P\left(x\right)$ and $E\left[X\right]=\int xd\left(1-P\left(x\right)\right)=-\int xdP\left(x\right)$.

Also $E\left[X\right]=-\int xp\left(x\right)dx$ where $p\left(x\right)$
is the derivative of $P\left(x\right)$.

The density is then $-p\left(x\right)$.

There is also a formula

> $E\left[X\right]=\int1-F\left(x\right)dx$.

It can be reduced from $E\left[X\right]=\int xdF\left(x\right)$ by partial integration.

That would lead to $E\left[X\right]=\int P\left(x\right)dx$,
so that is correct too.

Comment: Can you explain the reduction as well ?

Comment: You are talking about $R_{i}$. Is $i$ here meant to be an integer? If so then you are looking in a wrong direction.

Comment: If $i$ is not meant to be an integer then $P[R_{i}]=0$ for every $i$ and it will not bring you any further either. I should say: forget about indicators here.

Comment: No, I was talking about deriving $E[X] = \int 1 - F(x) dx$ from the expression $E[X] = \int x dF(x) $

Comment: Something like:$\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left(X>x\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{x}^{\infty}ydF\left(y\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{y}dxdF\left(y\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}ydF\left(y\right)$

Comment: There is a mistake in my former edit, but I cannot repair it any more. $\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{x}^{\infty}ydF\left(y\right)dx$ should be
replaced by $\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{x}^{\infty}dF\left(y\right)dx$

Comment: No problem , I got the main idea.

Comment: Last doubt regarding $P[X=x] = 0$ for continuous functions , so you mean to say we cannot have (for example) $P[X=x] = x$ , but this will also be continuous right ?

Comment: I am leaving now. Good luck with your study.

Comment: I am really thankful for your help . Can you  please clear my last doubt ?

Answer (score 0):

For every nonnegative random variable $X$,
$$
E[X]=\int_0^\infty P[X\geqslant x]\,\mathrm dx.
$$
This follows from the definition
$$
E[X]=\int_0^\infty x\,\mathrm d F(x).
$$
where $F(x)=P[X\leqslant x]$ (the function $F$ is called the CDF) and applying an integration by parts.

In your case, $P[X\geqslant x]=(1-x/a_1)\cdots(1-x/a_n)$ if $0\leqslant x\leqslant a$ and $P[X\geqslant x]=0$ if $x\geqslant a$, where $a=\min\{a_i\mid1\leqslant i\leqslant n\}$, hence
$$
E[X]=\int_0^a(1-x/a_1)\cdots(1-x/a_n)\,\mathrm dx.
$$

Comment: It think  $P[X > x] = (1 - x/a_{1}) ... (1-x/a_{n})$ and not $P[X \geqslant x]$

Comment: Here $P\left[X\geq x\right]=P\left[X>x\right]$. Characteristic for continuous
distributions is that $P\left[X=x\right]=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!, $P[X = x] = 0$ was going to be my next question :)

Comment: You are welcome. Now, my turn for a question: how come you accept an answer, **then** ask for a ton of explanations about it (to the point that even now the process is not over)?

Comment: @Did: Its just that I was satisfied by the answers, but only needed some more explanation in a middle step. Anyways, thanks to both of you for clearing my doubt :)

Comment: ?? Quote: `Can you please clear my last doubt ?`

Comment: Oh yeah , thanks for bringing this up , I am still not convinced on this part that why can't we have $P[X = x] = x$ (or any polynomial) and still have continuous distributions , what am I missing ?

Comment: ?? `I was satisfied by the answers`.

Comment: @Did: Please will you get over your sweet remarks and end this discussion now ? And why the hell should I be accountable to you for any of my statements ? And lastly we shouldn't be discussing over why I did this and that, but talking *math*

Comment: "why the hell should I be accountable to you for any of my statements ?" This is an interesting stance.